# What is the best way to implement OAuth on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth

I'm not a novice, but I'm primarily an iOS developer and haven't worked on Android in years. Unfortunately, I now need to implement an OAuth login in an existing Android app which is written in Kotlin.

I know the basics of OAuth and have implemented it recently in iOS apps.

I decided to put the code that opens the OAuth login page directly into the onCreate() method of the Android app's main activity. This works, in the sense that when the app runs, the web page opens. Also, I set up an intent-filter that responds to the redirect from the OAuth web site (it is an intent also attached to the main activity).

When I run the app, I can log in, the onCreate() method is called again, and I can get the results I need from intent.data. However, the app subsequently crashes when I try to navigate to a fragment that represents the app's home screen. The error in the log says "java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has been destroyed".

I know that the home screen fragment works and will appear if I open it directly without doing the OAuth.

I suspect I'm doing something illegal by having the redirect go to the main activity, but also, I need a piece of data (the "codeVerifier" string that I generated) when the login finishes. I could have the redirect open a new activity, but I don't know how I would communicate that string to it -- I tried using a static variable but Kotlin apparently doesn't support statics.

What is the best way to structure this?

Thanks.

Comment: please make question more concise and short.

Comment: Can you please show to the code where you redirect to the main activity. The onCreate and the manifest file code

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a good design, but it's probably too late for you to remake it. I would put all `OAuth` flow into a separate Activity (let's say OAuthActivity), in the Manifest I would set `noHistory` to true for that Activity, so user would not be able to get back to it after it perishes. In my `MainActivity` (which represents your home screen) I would set `launchMode` to `singleTask`, so I would be able to call it from the `OAuthActivity` without creating a double copy of it and pass the OAuth callback (I don't know what data will be there, some JWT?) there via some Intent (another alternative would be starting OAuthActivity via `registerForActivityResult` and return data via callback which better).

Still, I am not fond of this design, but it should work.

Kotlin does support static variables (please read the documentation), you can create a companion object for this like:

```
class A {
    companion object {
        var someVar: String = ""
    }
}
```

But usage of any persisted mutable static variables is strongly discouraged unless they are `private` and `const` (immutable).